# Vector Iterator not dereferencable (trying to manually reverse vector)

Tags: c++, function, iterator, stdvector, dereference

I'm trying to create a function which takes in a vector and simply reverses (manually). I'm aware of the existence of reverse(), but I ran into the "Vector iterator not dereferencable" problem and for educational purposes, I'd like to know what it means. I tried researching this problem and someone (on this forum) said that vect.end() is not dereferencable by definition, but from my understanding, using reverse_iterator is just reversing the ends, so following the logic; vect.rend should not be dereferencable.

```
vector<int> reverseVector(vector<int>);

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }

    vec = reverseVector(vec);

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

vector<int> reverseVector(vector<int> vect) 
{
    vector<int>::reverse_iterator ritr;
    for (ritr = vect.rbegin(); ritr != vect.rend(); ritr++)
    {
        vect.insert(vect.begin(), *ritr);
        vect.pop_back();
    }
    return vect;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting elements from the vector (popping from the back), which **invalidates** the reverse iterator.

---

You could just iterate through *half of the vector* and swap the elements, lke this:

```
void swap(int& a, int& b) {
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

vector<int> reverseVector(vector<int> vect) {
    const size_t origin_size = vect.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < origin_size/2; ++i)
        swap(vect[i], vect[origin_size - 1 - i]);
    return vect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the dereferencability or otherwise of `rend()`. You're modifying the vector while iterating over it, which invalidates the iterator.

To answer your original question, a `reverse_iterator` isn't just "reversing the ends" compared to a forward iterator. `rbegin()` is `end() - 1`, and `rend()` is `begin() - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an element to the vector, `ritr` may be invalidated thus the error

> Vector iterator not dereferencable.

Thus its better using an index as your loop variable or better a copy(temp) vector for reverse task.

Answer (score 1):

Both [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) and [pop_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) member functions modify the vector and invalidate iterators.

Answer (score 1):

A tip as design-issue: use always const-reference in a function, unless you really know what you are doing. So you will avoid stepping in traps like this. For example:

```
vector<int> reverseVector(const vector<int> &vect)
```

Now you wont have this problem, because you can not modify vect.